# Pushing data between ViewControllers not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, oop, viewcontroller

I am implementing a simple game in which the user tries to guess a randomly selected card.  They select their guess from a two-component picker (in FirstViewController), and in the next screen (SecondViewController) they can check if they are correct.  I am stuck right now trying to pass the guess the user selected to the screen where they can check.

In SecondViewController.h, I declare properties for both parts of the guess (number and suit) like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString * guessNumber;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString * guessSuit;
```

Then in didSelectRow in FirstViewController.h, I am trying to pass the info forward like this:

```
- (void) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    SecondViewController *secondVC = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
    if (component == 0){
        secondVC.guessNumber = _cardNumbers[row];
    }else{
        secondVC.guessSuit = _cardImages[row];
    }
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondVC animated:YES];

}
```

In viewDidLoad for SecondViewController, I NSLog the values of guessNumber and guessSuit, but it prints out null for both.

Clearly I am going wrong somewhere and the data isn't actually being passed, if anyone has any guidance about what I need to fix that would be amazing!

**EDIT:**
I have now changed the values to copy rather than assign, like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * guessNumber;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * guessSuit;
```

I have tried strong as well, and neither work.  The weird thing is that if I print out the value right after I assign it, like this:

```
secondVC.guessNumber = _cardNumbers[row];
NSLog(secondVS.guessNumber);
```

I get the right value. Now I am even further confused as it seems to be assigning the value but not saving it when I actually go to my second view controller.

Comment: Put `strong` instead of `assign` for `NSObject` (and so `NSString`)

Comment: @Larme I changed assign to strong and it still isn't working.  I was sure if you were telling me to change NSString to NSObject, but I tried both ways and I'm still getting null.

Comment: No no, I meant `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * guessNumber;`, Use strong for objects (not assign). Well, weak is acceptable too, but it's a different use.

Comment: I think the value you assign to the variable is null , i tried assign and it also prints the value but it recommended to make it strong

Comment: Actually, for `NSString` the property should be `copy`, not `strong`. But `strong` is way better than `assign`. Never use `assign` with object pointers.

Comment: Verify that `viewDidLoad` of `SecondViewController` is not being called before you try to assign a value to `guessNumber` or `guessSuit`.

Comment: @rmaddy I've now tried both strong and copy and neither work.  I also added a button that displays the two values upon being pressed so that if viewDidLoad was already being called, the values would still get printed.  But I'm still getting null

Answer (score 1):

The `assign` tells the `NSString *` property setter to save the pointer address instead of the OC object itself.

Both `_cardNumbers[row]` and `_cardImages[row]` return an autoreleased object which will be released after finishing your `didSelectRow` method, so you couldn't get the expected string values in your `viewDidLoad` of `SecondViewController`.

Use the `strong` or `copy` instead, it tells the property setter to increase the value's `retain count` by 1, so `SecondViewController` owns (`guessNumber` owns) the string value, you could get it in its life cycle all the time.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! However I've tried both strong and copy now and I am still getting null for my values

Comment: Implement the property setter method and make a breakpoint within it to debug to find out which caller update the value.

Answer (score 0):

NSString used copy is right . The problem is _cardNumbers and _cardImages ，let' see data source in _cardNumbers.